# Getting pagefile.sys' handle

Tags: c, winapi

How to use createfile api open pagefile.sys and get it's handle ? 
How does pagedfrg.exe tool open pagefile.sys and get it's file cluster info?

I want to using  FSCTL_QUERY_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS to get this file's cluster info. The intent is to send strictly this FSCTL to analyze the used clusters for statistical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, all defragment tools which try to defrag `pagefile.sys` work in offline mode (outside Windows). I think they write a kernel driver for that purpose, and use `ZwCreateFile()` to get the handle of `pagefile.sys` file. They are likely also utilyzing `ZwDeviceIoControlFile()` to access files in sector based.